# Как адаптировать вёрстку под Сафари?

Tags: html, css

Проблема такая: есть [сайт](http://mysolaris.xyz/octoland/index.html), который нормально отображается в мобильных браузерах, окромя Safari для iPhone. Прочитал на [flexbug](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#11-min-and-max-size-declarations-are-ignored-when-wrapping-flex-items) описание, решил править проблему, однако проверить свой код нигде не могу - iPhone у меня нет, попросить не у кого. Как править этот баг без визуальной проверки на правильность вёрстки?

Есть несколько блоков, которые имеют `flex-wrap: wrap`. Приведу один них для примера. Задал блокам `flex: 1 0 auto`, но всё равно мешается в кашу.

```css
.block--6 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fcb51d;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .block--6 {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.block--6 h2 {
  font-family: Bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin: 5vh 0 5vh 0;
}

.block--6__what {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .block--6__what {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.block--6__what .what__that {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 25vw;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .block--6__what .what__that {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.block--6__what .what__that p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: .9em;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .block--6__what .what__that p {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 90vw;
  }
}

.block--6__what .what__that .that__circle {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffc256;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .block--6__what .what__that .that__circle {
    width: 33vw;
    height: 33vw;
  }
}

.block--6__what .what__that .that__circle img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .block--6__what .what__that .that__circle img {
    max-width: 60%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block--6">
  <h2>ЧТО ВЫ ПОЛУЧАЕТЕ, ОБРАТИВШИСЬ К НАМ?</h2>
  <div class="block--6__what">
    <div class="what__that">
      <div class="that__circle">
        <img src="http://mysolaris.xyz/octoland/icons/tube.png">
      </div>
      <p>Видеоролик, увеличивающий продажи и генерирующий трафик на сайт</p>
    </div>
    <div class="what__that">
      <div class="that__circle">
        <img src="http://mysolaris.xyz/octoland/icons/presentation.png">
      </div>
      <p>Продвижение на площадках, где обитают ваши покупатели</p>
    </div>
    <div class="what__that">
      <div class="that__circle">
        <img src="http://mysolaris.xyz/octoland/icons/list.png">
      </div>
      <p>Долгосрочную стратегию работы с видеоконтентом</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex:1 работает нормально везде - https://yadi.sk/i/Gl9KzZKX3KCHWm

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Нет, к сожалению не работает